# How to save AttributedString with diacritics as proper RTF in swift?

Tags: swift, macos, unicode, nsattributedstring, rtf

I have an AttributedString which I generate programmatically with names and addresses. Both can contain diacritics, such as é, ü, î etc. They show correctly in an NSTextView (this is on macOS)
But when I save it as an RTF document, Apple does not replace the diacritics with their proper RTF encoding, so that `Grüter` suddenly becomes `GrÃ¼ter`. The correct rtf encoding for ü is `\'fc`

I have scrutinized Apple's [RTF Files and Attributed Strings](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Tasks/RTFAndAttrStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000164-BBCBJIBC) and  [Formatted Documents and Attributed Strings](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Articles/HTMLFilesandAttributedStrings.html) docs and NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute to no avail. 
I have written a rudimentary unicode value to RTF tag encoder, but am currently stuck with compound unicode scalars, like

Maybe I am missing something completely obvious, or is this a bug in Apple's RTF writing implementation?

Comment: Can you show a minimal self-contained example demonstrating the problem? How do you convert the attributed string to RTF?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Martin, I took the time to step away from the main project and create a playground.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I created a playground on https://github.com/axello/AttributedRTF, to figure out what I was doing wrong. I figured it out.

First of all, what I did wrong: I *import* an RTF text into a String, to manipulate certain tags and insert new texts. I do this on a String level, to keep the RTF tags intact. This worked for all the tags and ASCII text.

**However**, when I subsequently *export* the string, all the inserted strings with diacritics are not translated into their proper RTF code, because it assumes the string is just a bunch of data.

In my playground you can play with this:

- localString() : simply export an AttributedString as RTF;
- templateString() : read an RTF template in a String, do manipulations, and write the RTF. **This is wrong**;
- templateAttributedString() : read an RTF template into an AttributedString, do manipulations, and export the AttributedString as RTF.

In short: I need to *import* not as a String, but as an AttributedString, and insert AttributedStrings, which is slightly more cumbersome. Then I can *export* the AttributedString as an RTF, and the diacritics are properly converted into RTF.

Comment: But then your question is misleading: *"I have an **AttributedString** ... But when I save it as an RTF document, Apple does not replace the diacritics"*

Comment: So if you can't convert your 'properly modified' RTF strings back into AttributedString, what happens with the same diacritic when you created in AttributedString and write it back out to RTF? Does Apple do it in a non-standards-based way?